# How to run geolocation service in background when app is closed?

Tags: android, cordova

I'm building an Android app using Cordova based on HTML5,CSS,javaScript.It is a Location Reminder app,reminds people about their task when they arrived at that particular preset location.There is a start button,after clicking, it collect the current coordinates of the user and try to match with the previously given place's coordinate.It works fine when the app is on.But How to run this service when the app is closed?

Comment: Use geofencing.  Running geolocation like that is just about the worst (most time/battery consuming) way to do it.

Comment: The only plugin I've seen that handles this properly [cordova background geolocation](https://github.com/transistorsoft/cordova-background-geolocation-lt).  Unfortunately it costs money for the android version to work in production.